# How to set different flash message for same update operation in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, flash-message

I am updating a field in my db table which is either empty or already have some text. If it is empty after update **flash message** should be like '**Your intro added**' else like '**Your intro updated**'.

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzdrc.png)

This is my **controller**

```
function intro(){
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$table = 'users';
$this->load->model('my_model');
if($_POST){
date_to_save['intro'] = $this->input->post('intro');
$this->my_model->update($table, $user_id, $data_to_save);
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Intro added');
//$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Intro updated');
redirect('Home');
}
else{
$data = array();
if($this->my_model->get($table, $user_id)){
$data['intro'] = $this->my_model->get($table, $user_id);
}
$this->load->view('intro',$data);
}
}
```

And here is my sample **view**

```
 <form>
 My Intro:<br>
 <input type="text" name="intro" value="<?php isset($_POST['intro'])? $_POST['intro'] :'';?>"><br>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

I'm a beginner and looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are different methods to achieve this, one is below

**in view**

```
 <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="<?php isset($_POST['intro'])? 'edit' :'add';?>">
```

and **in your controller**

```
if($_POST['mode']=='add'){
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Intro added');
}
else{
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Intro updated');
}
```